# Can't run python in VScode after editing settings.json

Tags: python, virtualenv, visual-studio-code, pipenv

```
$ where python
C:\Users\Idan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
C:\Users\Idan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

The Error:

```
Idan@DESKTOP-A16D3QA MINGW64 ~/Desktop/ttt
$ C:\Users\Idan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe -u "c:\Users\Idan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\s.py"
bash: C:UsersIdanAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython38python.exe: command not found
```

deafault settings json file:

```
// Path to the pipenv executable to use for activation.
"python.pipenvPath": "pipenv",

// Path to the poetry executable.
"python.poetryPath": "poetry",

// Path to Python, you can use a custom version of Python by modifying this setting to include the full path.
"python.pythonPath": "python",
```

**settings.json**

**What I tried to do (integrate pipenv instead of venv):**

```
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Idan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe",
    "python.pipenvPath": "pipenv",
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.venvPath": "C:\\Users\\Idan\\.virtualenvs",

    ],
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

**other configuration I tried resulting in same error**:

```
 "python.venvPath": "C:\\Users\\Idan\\.virtualenvs",
    // this is the actual locatation
    // of the pythonpath C:\\Users\\Idan\\.virtualenvs\\Idan-iyfIpKqV\Scripts\python.exe
    "python.pythonPath": "$venvPath\\pipenvPath\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    //"python.pythonPath": "$venvPath\\ENV-NAME\\Scripts\\python.exe",
```

This is the full settings.json I have:
https://gist.github.com/IdanBanani/0d562770f14f3098debb6e1d47179e3f

previously, combining lines from these two sources was working (venv):
[https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/dotfiles/blob/master/settings/VSCode-Settings.json](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/dotfiles/blob/master/settings/VSCode-Settings.json%20https://github.com/xames3/xai_django/blob/bcaf169837d484d0bcf8686c18dc0529d1469034/.vscode/settings.json)
https://github.com/xames3/xai_django/blob/bcaf169837d484d0bcf8686c18dc0529d1469034/.vscode/settings.json

but I tried to replace to pipenv, and might try in the future to automatically set it to create and activate the virtualenv 
(pipenv install, pipenv shell) but not sure how easy it is

Also: I had to remove these lines of the **thefuck** project from .bashrc file because of error messages in the output console(maybe the installation/pip package got removed)

```
eval $(thefuck --alias)
# You can use whatever you want as an alias, like for Mondays:
eval $(thefuck --alias FUCK)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my current fix, but I don't think it's good enough for the generic case

Why does it keep creating the virtual env in a constant folder name Idan-iyfIpKqV?

```
 "python.venvPath": "C:/Users/Idan/.virtualenvs",
 "python.pythonPath": "C:/Users/Idan/.virtualenvs/Idan-iyfIpKqV/Scripts/python.exe",
```